# Chave incremental

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Gente, estou fazendo um web service com Java + Postgres. Eu defini minha tabela no Postgres da seguinte forma:

```sql
CREATE TABLE usuario
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nome character varying(40),
  idade integer,
  CONSTRAINT usuario_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE usuario
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

A chave `id` precisa ser incremental. No java eu fiz o seguinte método para **inserir**:

```java
public boolean inserirUsuario(Usuario usuario){

        try {


            Connection conn= ConectaPgAdmin.obtemConexao();


            String queryInserir = "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES**(null,?,?)**";

            PreparedStatement ppStm= conn.prepareStatement(queryInserir);

            //ppStm.setInt(1, usuario.getId());
            ppStm.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
            ppStm.setInt(2, usuario.getIdade());

            ppStm.executeUpdate();

            conn.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

Coloquei `null`, pois não é importante já que a chave será incremental. Porém quando executo, o eclipe me retorna que a chave Primária `id` não pode ser `null`.

Alguém sabe o que eu faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua SQL deveria ser assim:

```sql
INSERT INTO usuario (nome, idade) VALUES (?, ?)
```

O motivo é que o `auto_increment` só é aplicado se você não especificar o `id`, mas neste caso você estava especificando sim um valor de `id`, que é o valor `null`.

Além disso, use a sintaxe *try-with-resources* se você estiver no Java 7 ou superior, ou ao menos coloque o `conn.close()` dentro de um bloco *finally* se estiver no Java 6 ou inferior. O motivo é que do jeito que está, se ocorrer uma exceção, você acabará ficando com uma conexão zumbi aberta. Também é importante fechar o `PreparedStatement` adequadamente.

Portanto o seu código fica assim (Java 7 ou superior):

```java
public boolean inserirUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    String queryInserir = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, idade) VALUES (?, ?)";
    try (Connection conn = ConectaPgAdmin.obtemConexao();
            PreparedStatement ppStm = conn.prepareStatement(queryInserir)) {
        ppStm.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
        ppStm.setInt(2, usuario.getIdade());
        ppStm.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Java 6 ou inferior:

```java
public boolean inserirUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    String queryInserir = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, idade) VALUES (?, ?)";
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ppStm = null;
    try {
        try {
            conn = ConectaPgAdmin.obtemConexao();
            ppStm = conn.prepareStatement(queryInserir);
            ppStm.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
            ppStm.setInt(2, usuario.getIdade());
            ppStm.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            if (ppStm != null) ppStm.close();
            if (conn != null) conn.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada! Segui a sua dica e realmente deu certo! Muito Obrigada!